# How this Python Numpy ndarray slicing is working?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I wish to understand a piece of code that I have seen in python.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0ZmV.png)

in my particular case, face is a list and when the code is executed
x is 739
y is 229
w is 232
h is 349

image is a numpy.ndarray, I wanted to understand how the slicing of image is acctually working... which part of the image is acctually being selected?

I cant understand how the slicing is working

Comment: No images of code. Please post code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: Slicing syntax in numpy is identical to regular python slicing. What is your confusion?

Comment: It gets a smaller area of the image, from rows 229 to 578 and in those rows, columns 739 to 971

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/843953

Answer (score 0):

To slice a multi-dimensional array, you specify a standard slicing range (with up to 3 arguments seperated by `:`) for each dimension, and seperate the ranges with a `,`.

In this example, the array is sliced in the range of `y` up to `y + h` on one dimension, and `x` to `x + w` on the other.

read [this](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-ndarray-slice/) if for more examples